# How to send POST requests to Django Rest Framework without authentication?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to create a POST request from React to DRF for a normal search functionality: ANYONE on the site can input something in a search field and that data will be used to query the database. I do not need the users to be authenticated or anything. In DRF there needs to be an authentication class and I dont know which one to use. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set **`permission_classes`** and **`authentication_classes`** to empty

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView


class MyPublicView(APIView):
    permission_classes = []
    authentication_classes = []
```

You can use any DRF view instead of **`APIView`**. This procedure is same for all CBVs in DRF.